# Count of Orders By City

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, phpmyadmin

**My Query:**

```
select  distinct a.city, 
        (
            select count(*) 
            from sales_flat_order 
            where a.email=b.customer_email 
            group by a.city
        ) as 'lora' 
from sales_flat_order_address a, sales_flat_order b 
group by a.city
```

**Result:**

```
City1 : 15
City2: (NULL)
```

**Expected Result:**

```
City1 : 13
City2: 2
```

Comment: Can you include the table structure please? Can't really help otherwise..

Comment: these are tables from magento

Comment: thats not particularly helpful

Comment: which version of magento? 1.5?

Comment: i am using magneto 1.4.2

Comment: The real question to ask is why you are not using Magento's ORM for this? Avoiding direct SQL will yield better results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT count(sfoa.city) as count_of_city, sfoa.city 
FROM sales_flat_order as sfo 
LEFT JOIN sales_flat_order_address as sfoa ON sfo.entity_id=sfoa.parent_id 
WHERE sfoa.address_type="shipping" 
GROUP BY sfoa.city;
```

Is that what you are looking for (designed for magento 1.5)?

**EDIT**
Needed to have a filter for address type as every order will have a billing and shipping address.

Comment: how may i implement this query in magento grid

Comment: Basically i m implementing this in reporting grid.

Answer (score 4):

```
select a.city, count(*) as 'lora' 
from sales_flat_order_address a
        INNER JOIN sales_flat_order b 
            ON a.email=b.customer_email 
group by a.city
```

Comment: +1 : I can't be sure this is what the OP wants, as the example SQL has to many issues.  But this looks like a very reasonable inferrence.

Comment: Scorpio's solution is correct. That your data doesn't match your expectations is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from sales_flat_order where a.email=b.customer_email group by a.city
```

can return multiple rows. it can not be used in a SELECT clause as query field, unless EMAIL field has some unique index e.g. besides, it contains syntax error from a point of view of ANSI SQL. GROUP BY clause is redundand here

Comment: Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 'a.email' in 'where clause'

Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Answer (score 0):

seems problem in no where clause for binding sales_flat_order_address a and sales_flat_order b